# Is there any different behavior between Calendar#add(Calendar.MONTH, months) and LocalDate#plusMonth(months)?

Tags: java, localdate, date, java.util.calendar

I'm working on some legacy code where `java.util.Calendar` is used for date related calculations (basically adding months). Now I want to replace `java.util.Calendar` by `java.time.LocalDate` in the code but I don't want to change the behavior. So, I've been looking for a source which clarifies that they yield same result for the same calculation for any case but I can't find any.

Especially I want to know if is there a date that makes them yield a different result between:

`Calendar#add(Calendar.MONTH, months)`

and

`LocalDate#plusMonth(months)`

I've tested some corner cases (e.g. a leap year related dates) and they seem to yield the same result but I can't be 100% sure with that. Isn't there any official information about that or some known difference between them?

Comment: Have you consulted [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)?

Comment: Yes but it’s unclear that if they are 100% compatible in terms of date related calculations

Comment: Just to be clear: You should ***never* be using `Calendar` or `Date`**. Those classes really are that bad — [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) was adopted for good reason! To interoperate with legacy code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can easily convert back-and-forth. Look to new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes. For `Calendar`, cast to `GregorianCalendar`, then call `toZonedDateTime`. For `java.util.Date`, call `toInstant`. And go the other direction:  `GregorianCalendar.from( myZonedDateTime )` and `Date.from( myInstant )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

If:

- You are sure that your [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) is really a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) (by far the most commonly used subclass), and…
- Your dates don’t go more than 100 years back, then…

…you can safely use [`LocalDate#plusMonth(months)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths(long)) instead of [`Calendar#add(Calendar.MONTH, months)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,int)).

**Details**

Congratulations on the decision to migrate from the old and poorly designed `Calendar` class to `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This will be an improvement to your code base.

You are correct, the methods you mention are used for the same purpose and generally work the same. So when you migrate from `Calendar` to java.time, if you find that `LocalDate` is the right new class to use, then you will use `LocalDate#plusMonth(months)` where you used `Calendar#add(Calendar.MONTH, months)` before.

Differences include:

- The [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) class is an abstract superclass for classes representing dates (and times) in many different calendar systems ([Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), [Buddhist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_calendar) and more), a `LocalDate` is always in the proleptic Gregorian calendar. Since each calendar system has its own definition of what a month is, adding a number of months in a calendar other than the Gregorian calendar can give quite different results from what `LocalDate.plusMonths` gives you.
- If your dates go back in history it will also make a minor difference that `LocalDate` uses the [*proleptic* Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar). This means that it doesn’t use the [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) for dates where it was in use centuries ago.
- While `Calendar.add` modifies the `Calendar` object that you call it on, [`LocalDate.plusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths(long)) returns a *new* `LocalDate` object with the new date.
- While for going backward in the calendar you need to pass a negative number of months to [`Calendar::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,int)), `LocalDate` has a convenient [`minusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusMonths(long)) method that you will typically want to use instead of `plusMonths` (both work, though).
- The range of dates that each class can represent is different. I don’t readily remember the minimum and maximum date for each. On `Calendar`/`GregorianCalendar`, see their various methods such as `getGreatestMinimum​` & `getLeastMaximum​`. For `LocalDate`, see the constants: [`MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#MAX) & [`MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN).